Add user to existing online meeting
I want to add users to an existing online meeting via graph and a flow. The flow runs without issues but the user are not added.
These are my inputs:
{
"uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/7e55f577-1c53-474b-b48c-a913b9cb0913/onlineMeetings/MSo3ZTU1ZjU3Ny0xYzUzLTQ3NGItYjQ4Yy1hOTEzYjljYjA5MTMqMCoqMTk6bWVldGluZ19ObVkzTnpkalpEQXRNbVE1WmkwME9HTmxMV0kxT0RndE1tTmpaV1ZrTkRFMk5EZGhAdGhyZWFkLnYy",
"method": "PATCH",
"headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json "
}
"body": {
    "participants": {
        "attendees": [
            {
                "upn": "xx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}

}
What do I wrong?
